# Unable to start devops build agents using VMSS scale sets

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

**Description**: Created a VMSS scale set using a custom image from VS2019 VM and started a devops build agent in Azure devops
**Issue**: After creating the devops agent, the scale set instances are struck in creating state and agent is not starting

[image]
[image]

**VMSS Configuration:**
{
"vmss": {
"doNotRunExtensionsOnOverprovisionedVMs": false,
"overprovision": false,
"platformFaultDomainCount": 1,
"provisioningState": "Succeeded",
"singlePlacementGroup": false,
"timeCreated": "2022-04-28T01:31:02.4410107+00:00",
"uniqueId": "",
"upgradePolicy": {
"mode": "Manual",
"rollingUpgradePolicy": {
"maxBatchInstancePercent": 20,
"maxUnhealthyInstancePercent": 20,
"maxUnhealthyUpgradedInstancePercent": 20,
"pauseTimeBetweenBatches": "PT0S"
}
},
"virtualMachineProfile": {
"networkProfile": {
"networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
{
"name": "vmsca150eNic",
"properties": {
"dnsSettings": {
"dnsServers": []
},
"enableAcceleratedNetworking": false,
"enableIPForwarding": false,
"ipConfigurations": [
{
"name": "vmsca150eIPConfig",
"properties": {
"privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
"subnet": {
"id": "/subscriptions//resourceGroups/AzureDevops-BuildAgents-TESTRK-Windows/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/AzureDevops-BuildAgents-TESTRK-Windows-vnet/subnets/default",
"resourceGroup": "AzureDevops-BuildAgents-TESTRK-Windows"
}
}
}
],
"primary": true
}
}
]
},
"storageProfile": {
"imageReference": {
"id": "/subscriptions//resourceGroups/AzureDevops-BuildAgents-TESTRK-Windows/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/vmGalleryWindows/images/VMSSImageDefinition",
"resourceGroup": "AzureDevops-BuildAgents-TESTRK-Windows"
},
"osDisk": {
"caching": "ReadWrite",
"createOption": "FromImage",
"diskSizeGB": 127,
"managedDisk": {
"storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
},
"osType": "Windows"
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: what VM sku are you using? did you ensure all required firewall/nsg rules are opened for the VMSS?

Comment: The VMs should go into a failed state after they attempt to start and fail, that should tell you the error. My guess is something is wrong with the image or a startup task. To keep DevOps from deleting the VMs check the `Save an unhealthy agent for investigation` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting-issues

Comment: @KedMardemootoo used this blog to create vmss https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops 
As per this, a load balance is not required for a devops agent, so didnt worry about the firewall rules

Comment: Generally the agent will be installed using a VM extension, are you able to check the extension and see if there any useful logs there?

Comment: @RohithKorupalli Have you resolved this issue?